# Is there a way to export my current vim maps and functions as a .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I lost my latest version of my .vimrc and I have no snapshots of it anywhere but I do have a vim still open that has the new functions and mappings. I was hoping that maybe someone would know how to "export" that running vim's maps and functions out to a file so I could recreate the .vimrc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`:mkvimrc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3amkvimrc) (or [`:mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3amksession) if you also want to save any buffer-local state too).

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work as it does not save the functions.

Comment: There's no built-in convenience for saving functions that i know of, but you can list the defined functions and their bodies with [`:function`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:function). This should allow you to manually save the ones you want.

Comment: Thanks again but no. From the help: ":fu[nction]  List all functions and their arguments." It does not list the body of the function as you claim. I am not trying to be rude but I do not want people to think this issue is resolved. As it stands now I am still unaware of any way to see the body of the function.

Comment: @stephen -- No, Piet D. is right.  You should get entire body if you enter just the function name with no parens, e.g., ':function MyFunction'.  This will list body to screen, you can use a version of the :redirect command to save to variable or file, so it's fully possible to automate the process.  (Maybe there's more direct way than using :redirect but offhand I don't see it.)

Comment: Well I'll be damned, ":function {name}" does work. I must be dense. My sincerest apologies to Piet and greatest thanks to Piet and Herbert. This is really great news and will save me a ton of time.