# Retrieve `.vimrc` content used to initiate the current vim session

Tags: vim, macvim

After removing an old `.vimrc` (no backup) I realised that there were a few things I still need from it. I still have a couple of vim sessions open which used the old `.vimrc` file.

Is there a way to output the contents of the `.vimrc` file that was used to initiate the current vim session?

Comment: Related post: [Is there a way to export my current vim maps and functions as a .vimrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3877348/438329)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:help :mkvimrc
```

is your best bet.

Comment: This is definitely the closest thing that I could wish for!

Answer (score 1):

You can type `:scriptnames<Return>` to display the list of vimrc files and other scripts presently loaded in the order they were loaded.

Comment: This lists the filenames, unfortunately I cannot look in the content of not existing file

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can get some info from :mksession and then look at the session script it creates.